# What's the proper way to remove this padding from my Twitter Bootstrap navigation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, padding

A picture tells a thousand words..

[image: padded nav]

I want rid of that nasty bit of padding on the left. How can I do it? Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="li-home active">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="li-abc">
                    <a href="#">Abc</a>
                </li>
                <li class="li-def">
                    <a href="#">Def</a>
                </li>
                <li class="li-ghi">
                    <a href="#">Ghi</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's there under the navigation ? (code)

Comment: Just another `<div class="container">` with a bunch of `<div class="row">...</div>`s inside

Comment: Then, put your `navbar` into a `row` because `row` has a `margin-left: -20px` that's why your content looks like this.

Comment: You should put that as an answer and I'll mark is as correct. That's done the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `navbar` into a `row` because `row` has a `margin-left: -20px` that's why your content looks like this.

Comment: This has fixed that problem but I'm not quite done with you yet.. you've made me realise that my whole site is shifted 20px over to the left. How can I avoid this? Should I not be using `.row` for this?

Comment: I don't know why `.row` has that `margin-left` but using `.row` looks best practice according to documentation. So keep using it.

Comment: From a little experimenting now it seems to be best only if you're splitting the row into several `spanX`s, if you're keeping something the full width of the container then you don't seem to need the `.row`